# Windows 10 Built in VPN L2TP/IPsec Authentication

Tags: vpn, cisco-asa, windows-10

I am trying to set up an Remote-VPN IPsec ikev1 from a Windows 10 built in VPN-client to a Cisco asa 5505, using a L2TP/IPsec runnel with a Pre-shared key and xAuth. 
After some struggle, I manage to complete both IPsec Phase 1 and Phase 2. But I still got this error on the Windows side when trying to connect:

> The remote connection was denied because the user name and password
>   combination you provided is not recognized, or the selected
>   authentication protocol is not permitted on the remote access server”.

On the Windows side, I have under "Allowed protocols" checked both Chap and MS-Chap v2.
On the Cisco ASA, I have allowed MS-Chap v2 on the DefaultRAGroup, and the Cisco VPN debugger doesn't show me anything specific error about this either.

**Will** **post** parts of my running configuration if needed, but I have a feeling that the problem is from the Windows side.

**Anyone succeeded with what I am trying to do here? Or know some details about Windows built-in VPN Client authentication methods that I don't?**

***EDIT***

Added a screenshot of some VPN Debug messages. Notice the "PHASE 2 COMPLETE" message in blue, and then the client send a Terminate message. Also notice "Security negotiation complete for User(). There should be a user stated in there.. 
[image]

Comment: Is the windows account you are logged into trying to connect the VPN an administrator account?

Comment: Yes it is a local administrator account,  in a non-domain environment

Comment: Ok so the IPsec part is working ok (i.e. you get to 'phase 2 completed') but now the L2TP auth is failing. "debug aaa authentication", "debug ppp authentication/negotiation" (if I remember well, doing this from memory, you may want to check for similar commands) may help. Also, I think I remember someone solving a similar problem by using MS-CHAP (not v2) which to me didn't make any sense, but perhaps it's something to try.

Answer (score 0):

This is often the case when the AAA-Server and PPP combination is wrong. Only these combinations are supported:

```
LOCAL    : PAP, MSCHAPv1, MSCHAPv2
RADIUS   : PAP, CHAP, MSCHAPv1, MSCHAPv2, EAP-Proxy
TACACS+  : PAP, CHAP, MSCHAPv1
LDAP     : PAP
NT       : PAP
Kerberos : PAP
```

See [this reference](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa82/configuration/guide/config/l2tp_ips.html). You have to select that appropriately at the Connection Profile (Advanced->PPP).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using local authentication and MS-CHAP, then you need to encode your password hashes using unicode and MD4. You do that by appending the msschap (or in some versions, the nt-encrypted) keyword like this:

```
username test password cisco mschap
username test2 password cisco2 nt-encrypted
```

Then you will be able to successfully authenticate.